# Header message just like at Stack Overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, header

This is the first time I visited stack overflow and I saw a beautiful header message which displays a text and a close button.

The header bar is fixed one and is great to get the attention of the visitor. I was wondering if anyone of you guys know the code to get the same kind of header bar.

Answer (score 25):

Quick pure JavaScript implementation:

```
function MessageBar() {
    // CSS styling:
    var css = function(el,s) {
        for (var i in s) {
            el.style[i] = s[i];
        }
        return el;
    },
    // Create the element:
    bar = css(document.createElement('div'), {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        position: 'fixed',
        background: 'orange',
        width: '100%',
        padding: '10px',
        textAlign: 'center'
    });
    // Inject it:
    document.body.appendChild(bar);
    // Provide a way to set the message:
    this.setMessage = function(message) {
        // Clear contents:
        while(bar.firstChild) {
            bar.removeChild(bar.firstChild);
        }
        // Append new message:
        bar.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
    };
    // Provide a way to toggle visibility:
    this.toggleVisibility = function() {
        bar.style.display = bar.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    };
}
```

How to use it:

```
var myMessageBar = new MessageBar();
myMessageBar.setMessage('hello');
// Toggling visibility is simple:
myMessageBar.toggleVisibility();
```

Comment: Rather than have a toggle after the append line just do this:
 bar.style.display = message === '' ? 'none' : 'block';

Then when you want to get rid of the bar just:
 myMessageBar.setMessage('');

Comment: Toggling visibility seems like a much more intuitive API to me; I would expect a blank message to show as a blank message, rather than no bar at all.

Comment: How would you invoke myMessageBar.toggleVisibility() as an onclick for the bar?

Comment: @leif81 An onclick handler. So add, `bar.onclick = this.toggleVisibility;` to the last line of MessageBar. @999 - Nice. http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/VUCpK/ (has the onclick for the bar)

Answer (score 11):

## Update:

---

## [Check out the DEMO](http://jsbin.com/apiri4/3)

**Code Used:**

```
$(function(){
  $('#smsg_link').click(function(){
  showMessage('#9BED87', 'black', 'This is sample success message');
  return false;
});

$('#imsg_link').click(function(){
  showMessage('#FFE16B', 'black', 'This is sample info message');
  return false;
});

$('#emsg_link').click(function(){
  showMessage('#ED869B', 'black', 'This is sample error message');
  return false;
});
});



/*
showMessage function by Sarfraz:
-------------------------
Shows fancy message on top of the window

params:
  - bgcolor:     The background color for the message box
  - color:     The text color of the message box
  - msg:       The message text
*/
var interval = null;

function showMessage(bgcolor, color, msg)
{
    $('#smsg').remove();
    clearInterval(interval);

    if (!$('#smsg').is(':visible'))
    {
        if (!$('#smsg').length)
        {
            $('<div id="smsg">'+msg+'</div>').appendTo($('body')).css({
                position:'fixed',
                top:0,
                left:0,
                width:'98%',
                height:'30px',
                lineHeight:'30px',
                background:bgcolor,
                color:color,
                zIndex:1000,
                padding:'10px',
                fontWeight:'bold',
                fontSize:'18px',
                textAlign:'center',
                opacity:0.8,
                margin:'auto',
                display:'none'
            }).slideDown('show');

            interval = setTimeout(function(){
                $('#smsg').animate({'width':'hide'}, function(){
                    $('#smsg').remove();
                });
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you want to create your own, check out the [`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) function of jQuery.

Comment: i'm looking for something that moves the entire website down, not like a dropdown menu

Comment: @harrison: Not sure what you mean then, can u give an example?

Comment: yeah, hold on. i'll look for one online.

Comment: i guess it's called flash messages? i can't find an example, except when i uncover a new badge on stackoverflow

Comment: he means that when the message is displayed the contents of the site should not remain stationary. They should be pushed down by the message. The message should not cover up the content.

Answer (score 4):

The relevant css would include:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
```

[More information about `position:fixed`](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp):

> An element with position: fixed is positioned at the specified coordinates relative to the browser window. The element's position is specified with the "left", "top", "right", and "bottom" properties. The element remains at that position regardless of scrolling. Works in IE7 (strict mode)

If IE6 support is important to you, you may wish to [research workarounds](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS291US304&q=position+fixed+ie6&btnG=Search).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative method using jQuery which would also slide up/down on show/hide.

Add the following HTML right after the `<body>` tag in your page:

```
<div id="msgBox">
    <span id="msgText">My Message</span>           
    <a id="msgCloseButton" href='#'>close</a>
</div>
```

Add this CSS to your stylesheet

```
#msgBox {
    padding:10px; 
    background-color:Orange; 
    text-align:center; 
    display:none; 
    font:bold 1.4em Verdana;
}
#msgCloseButton{
    float:right;    
}
```

And finally here is the javascript to setup the close button and functions to show and hide the message bar:

```
/* Document Ready */
$(function () {
    SetupNotifications();
});

SetupNotifications = function () {
    //setup close button in msgBox
    $("#msgCloseButton").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        CloseMsg();
    });
}

DisplayMsg = function (sMsg) {
    //set the message text
    $("#msgText").text(sMsg);
    //show the message
    $('#msgBox').slideDown();
}

CloseMsg = function () {
    //hide the message
    $('#msgBox').slideUp();
    //clear msg text
    $("#msgtText").val("");
}
```

To perform a simple test you could try this:

```
<a href='#' onclick="javascript: DisplayMsg('Testing');">Show Message!</a>
```

Comment: i think this is the better solution, simply because it moves the entire page down!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$("#bar").slideUp();
```

However, here I think they fade out first the bar then they bring the main container up, so that'd be something like that:

```
$("#bar").fadeOut(function(){
    $("#container").animate({"top":"0px"});
});
```