# How do I make the jquery slide down effect like the one stackoverflow uses?

Tags: javascript, slide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Header message just like at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605291/header-message-just-like-at-stack-overflow)

I want to make an effect with either javascript or jquery that creates a bar that slides down at the top of the window with a prompt, not sure how to google this or code this.